# Почему "фамильярность" — синоним "панибратства"?

Tags: этимология

Обычно обращение по фамилии является более официальным, чем по имени. По крайней мере, в школе я терпеть не могла, когда ко мне обращались по фамилии. Но почему слово "фамильярность" — синоним панибратского обращения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не совсем синонимы. Ну или, так скажем, - неполные синонимы.  
Есть небольшая разница в значениях.
Панибратство, как вытекает из названия - стиль поведения, относящийся ко всему кругу общения. Т.е. такой индивидуум считает себя со всеми в близких отношениях, со всеми "на ты". Часто употребляется в отношении лиц, панибратствующих со всеми вышестоящими, более известными, знаменитыми людьми. Хотя те его знать не знают.
Фамильярничать же можно (обычно так и есть) с кем-то конкретным, одним человеком.     
Остальное - у Людмилы. Я присоединяюсь.

Answer (score 3):

Называть по фамилии - не фамильярность, а "фамильничанье"(разговорное)
А фамильярность и панибратство - действительно синонимы, потому что смысл похож:
ФАМИЛЬЯРНОСТЬ
(лат. familiaritas - дружба, короткое знакомство). Простое, панибратское обхождение с кем - либо.(Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка.- Чудинов А.Н., 1910.)
 Обхождение запанибрата- бесцеремонное обхождение.

Фасмер: Фамильярный . Происходит от лат. familiaris «домашний, семейный; приятельский», далее из familia «домочадцы, челядь», от famulus «слуга,служитель» (дальнейшая этимология неясна). Русск. фамилья́рный — уже у Остермана, 1718 г.; заимств. через польск. familiarny.

Т.е. фамильярное обращение - это обращение к чужому так же просто и близко, как в своей семье.

Answer (score 0):

Фамильярность и фамилия имеют значения. И "фамильярность" с "панибратством" - разные вещи, кстати.

*Фамильярность* - от латинского familiaris ("домашний, семейный, приятельский") через французов и (для нас) поляков.

*Фамилия* - более позднее приобретение от Петра Лексеича для внедрения того, чего до него не было

Comment: >И "фамильярность" с "панибратством" - разные вещи, кстати.  
  
Да, но хотелось бы подробностей. Как именно Вы это понимаете.

Answer (score -2):

1) Фамильярность ничего общего не имеет с панибратством.
2)Что такое панибратство больше могут понять на Украине или Польше, в России такой термин понятен больше на юге(Кубанцам и Донцам), панибратство в исходнике это термин характеризующий вольность общения в закрытой военной касте, где все имеют равные права кроме тех кто выбран на кругу и при исполнении (кому делегированы полномочия гетмана\атамана\сотника и т.д.), для того что полностью понять термин - надо понимать что такое боевое братство , и много других терминов ... таких к примеру что в панибратском кругу нельзя опростоволосится... , для понимания надо это рассматривать в семантике казаков \ вольных людей \ закрытого рыцарского клуба \шляхты, тогда возможно понимание сути. Панибратство в чистом виде и казацкой семантике имеет положительный смысл.
3) Фамильярность - это слово западноевропейское и подразумевает непринуждённость в общении (обычная в родственном \семейном кругу, от латинского - родство, близость) не путать с термином "фамильничать" пришедшего из утверждения чистоты рода\ законности рождения... 
4) Братание - ритуал известный со скифских времён.